# Lock mysql table column

Tags: mysql, locking

is it possible to lock selected columns in a mysql table, example table1 with columns: col1, col2, where col1 would be locked and now updating can be made while col2 is open for updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to prevent values in col1 from being updated. If that's the case, then you might want to look into using a UPDATE [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) with BEFORE UPDATE clause on table1 and implement the logic that would only allow updating values in col2 but not col1 in that trigger.

Comment: so what would I include in the statement seeing that all i want to do is prevent updating

Comment: In the trigger you'd just need to run UPDATE using all the values from original UPDATE but value for col1.